# Disabling "Download sources and javadoc" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, javadoc

I'm using Eclipse 20210312-0638

I have unchecked "Download artifact sources" and "Download artifact javadoc" from preferences (First picture). It's still downloading them (2nd picture). Is there any other configuration that I should change?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Silly question, but did you restart eclipse?

Comment: @JFabianMeier yep, restarted and also tried starting with -clearPersistedState -clean flags

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Someone already filled a bug at Eclipse:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576112

Apparently, it's fixed in M2E, but not yet released. Though, you can update on the latest snapshot as explained here:
https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/252#issuecomment-926379620

It solved the issue for me.

---

Until the release in Eclipse, you must add this update-site:
https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/snapshots/1.18.3/latest/

---

Accoriding to @Nis this is now released in the standard Eclipse update-site, so you don't need to add the preceding update-site anymore

Comment: Thanks! This problem was driving me crazy. I have updated m2e e now the error disappeared.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I will update my whole team to use this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Does anybody know when we can expect a regular update to fix this (i.e. not a snapshot)?

Comment: Go to Help | Check for Updates. There is a new version of m2e available (1.19.0.20211116-0804). Looks like it has been working for me :-)

Answer (score 6):

I've managed to stop this by clicking on the red square button near the end of the line with "Download sources and javadoc" progression bar in "Progress" tab. This red button appears for a fraction of a second, so you have to be quick with clicking it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please improvise your comments by briefing more

Comment: this fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I also try to work around it by clicking quickly on the stop command in the Progress tab. However it doesn't last, as soon as I change any code again, Eclipse (probably m2e), seems to refresh most Maven projects and restarts the cycle  of never-ending download attempts. I wish there was a permanent solution.