# Maven build - Download sources and javadoc (Sleeping) OK

Tags: selenium, maven, pom.xml

When I am trying to save the `pom.xml` file, Eclipse is stuck in an endless loop with build status as -  ***Download sources and javadoc (Sleeping) OK*** while associating sources and javadoc with classpath.

[image]

My POM file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sachindra</groupId>
    <artifactId>wwe</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The Maven setting configurations is such:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a known issue, jump to here:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69339198/11543023)

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue,

In my case I updated Chrome and later i downloaded compatible chrome webdriver, and made changes in code respect to that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).